# Hide elements using jquery based on option select

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have two forms and a selector.

This is my code --

```
<select>
<option value="1">Pay</option>
<option value="2">Goog</option>
</select>

<form id="pp">
<input type="text">
</form>

<form id="cc">
<input type="text">
</form>
```

Now if option 1 is selected i want to hide form CC. if 2 hide form PP.

How do i do it with js or jquery? thanks

Comment: possible duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655911/jquery-show-an-element-from-select-drop-down-hide-it-when-other-option-selected  but I am sure very much related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script>
    function Hide(val)
    {
    if(val==1)
{
    document.getElementById('cc').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('pp').style.display='inline';
    }
    if(val==2)
{ 
   document.getElementById('pp').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('cc').style.display='inline';
    }
} 
   </script>

    <select onchange="Hide(this.value);">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Pay</option>
    <option value="2">Goog</option>
    </select>

    <div id="pp">
    <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div id="cc">
    <input type="text">
    </div>
```

Comment: this is plain javascript, OP would prefer a jquery based answer I guess

Comment: @ngen says you have a spelling mistake `if(val==1){document.getElementById('cc').style.display='none';document.getElementById('pp').style.display='inlinr';}`  - should be `document.getElementById('pp').style.display='inline';`

Comment: and not even very good code.. `<script>`.. which type? you should add `type="text/javascript"` - and properly indent your code

Answer (score 8):

Try this (using jQuery):

```
$("select").bind("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        $("#pp").show();
        $("#cc").hide();
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "2") {
        $("#pp").hide();
        $("#cc").show();
    }
});
```

Additionally, you could hide both forms using `.hide()` as shown above before the user selects any option.

- [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is attaching an event handler to the "change" event of the select box.  This is fired when the user changes what option is selected.
- Inside the handler, [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is used to determine the value of the currently selected option.
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) are used on the correct forms, depending on which option was selected.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/faqZg/