# Display input box on particular value selected in select menu using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want display input field only if "Car" is selected in select menu given below using jquery.

```
<select name="type">
  <option value="plane">Plane</option>
  <option value="car">Car</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="name">
```

Is it possible do with jQuery ?

Comment: Do you know what the change event is? Do you know how to find the value of a select? Do you know how to show/hide an element? If you know all three, put them together.

Comment: Why did this question get downvoted? What is not clear about it? Is that a goddam reflex your highness, oh StackOverflow experts, have to click on that arrow down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

**Dom:**

```
<select name="type">
  <option value="plane">Plane</option>
  <option value="car">Car</option>
</select>
<input class="hideme" type="text" name="name">
```

**Jscode**:

```
$('select').change(function(){
if($(this).val()=== "car")
$('.hideme').show();
else
    $('.hideme').hide();
}).change();
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLVN5/1/)**

Comment: Also, on document ready you should check the select value too :)

Comment: Good catch.We can trigger change event for select on document.ready.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `toggle` method:

```
$(function () {
    $('select[name=type]').change(function () {
        $('input[name=name]').toggle(this.value === "car" ? true : false);
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: It's about visibility, you know ...

Comment: @SilviuBurcea i don't understand your comment?!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood your toggle function. I thought you're setting the input value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="type" onchange="showTextBox(this.value)">
  <option value="plane">Plane</option>
  <option value="car">Car</option>
</select>
<input  type="hidden" id="MyBox">
<script>
function showTextBox(item){
      if(item=="car"){$('#MyBox').show();}
}
</script>
```

Comment: The `hideme` class is not defined in your answer. You don't hide `MyBox` if "Plane" is chosen, and you don't show `MyBox` on page load if "Car" is selected.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann Please read the question properly , i won't required hideme class at all. I can simply put type="hidden". Why -1 to this answer , i don't understand.

Comment: your edit has fixed the fact that the input box was visible when "Car" wasn't selected. That was the reason for the down vote; it didn't provide a working answer the question. The vote has been removed now that you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can retrieve the values through the tag, then use a statement to determine whether or not to display the input field or container that it is in.

Here is a reference to retrieving these values:
[How do I get the text value of a selected option?](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)

Here is an answer I just found on SO actually, that does something similar to what you are looking for:
[jQuery: show an element from select drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655911/jquery-show-an-element-from-select-drop-down-hide-it-when-other-option-selecte)

Answer (score 1):

You could add an empty option and do this:

```
$("[name='type']").change(
 function(){
  if($(this).val() == "car"){
   $("[name='name']").show();
   }else{
    $("[name='name']").hide();
   }
 }
);
```